# DisplaySuite, but for fields?

Tags: 7, entities, display-suite

Ok, DisplaySuite is nice, Views is nice. But, I often find myself doing PHP coding using EFQ to achieve the result I need.

Thing is, dealing with render arrays and field API is a massive pain, especially when so many of the settings can easily be configured using the existing UIs.

So, I'm wondering if there is a module that I've overlooked that would allow me to configure my field settings for entities/nodes, and then just call that field configuration in my code.

Basically DisplaySuite, but for individual fields only.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything but I'd be willing to help build something on drupal.org.

Comment: I'm just at the end of a big project. If I have time after, I'd like to dig into this a bit too. This module looks interesting (http://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_settings), and could be an API that just needs wrapping in a management UI.